# Buddha in Ardha-Naarishvara sculpture in Badami Cave temples?

Tags: india, hinduism, buddhism

[Badami caves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badami_cave_temples) are a series of cave-temples built between 6th and 8th century. In the first cave, dedicated to hindu god Lord Shiva, there is an image of "Ardha-Naarishvara".

[image]

I was intrigued by the figure to the left of the deity - it shows a starved man with long ears. I could not help but think of starved Buddha image seen elsewhere. If it is indeed Buddha, it seems to me a gentle put-down of buddhism - buddha himself praying to hindu deity.

When I asked the local guide he told me that it is not Buddha but a male-chauvinist devotee of Shiva cursed by Shiva's consort Gauri, but I am not too convinced.

So my question: do we know what the temple builders intended by the starving figure? Opinion of experts of that era would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The figure is [Bringhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhringi), who refused to worship [Parvati/Gauri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parvati) and is an important part in the legend of [Ardhanarishvara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardhanarishvara), and is often depicted with Shiva:

[image: Bringhi]
[image: Bringhi]

Comment: Tell me you didn't know this of the top of your head.

Comment: @MonsterTruck: To be honest, all that was needed was to look up Ardhanarishvara. It's all there.

Comment: @Lennart - Thanks for your answer. I had a couple of related follow up questions. Do we know for sure that "Bringhi" predates 6th century i.e. is not a mythical story born _after_ the cave temples were built/carved? Why does he look eerily like starving Buddha?

Comment: @Abhilash He looks like a starving Buddha, because the curse on him removed his flesh and blood, so he is literally just skin and bones. This is explained in the linked article, I suggest you read it.